# Getting error "command not found" on every command in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

I was having some big problems with mysql yesterday so I uninstalled it on my macbook pro and when I reinstalled it mysql seems to work, but now I cant run a single command in VSCODE, I tried with "nodemon server.js", "yarn start" and many more. All I get now is a command not found error, like this: "bash: yarn: command not found".

"ls" seems to work fine though.

I have no clue what to do or what i might have done to create this problem.

What can be wrong and what can I do?

Comment: Now I also got a message saying: "You have new mail in /var/mail/UN". When clicking the link it says that: "/bin/sh: /tmp/iu.sh: No such file or directory". Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 1):

Puh! I finally I solved it. For some reason which I really don't understand, when uninstalling mysql, it also uninstalled yarn and nodemon. So what I had to do was install yarn with homebrew and then install nodemon with yarn.

Now things are working as they should, and I can stop talking to myself over the web.